# how to change input value with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in a html form I have an input with text type, and select menu with a few options!

I want to change the value of input to that options value I select it from Select menu
I think I can do it with jQuery or js

example:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="some text">
<select onchange="onCategoryChange(this)" name="catlist[]">
<option value="1" style="color: black">text1</option>
<option value="2" style="color: black">text2</option>
<option value="3" style="color: black">text3</option>
<option value="4" style="color: black">text4</option>
</select>
```

I think you understand that the input is the title and options are the categories!
If someone select option with value=1 then the value of input would be "text1"
I want that the value of title and category be same!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("select[name='catlist[]']").change(function () {
    $("#inputID").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/chKnK/)

F.Y.I.

From the [**:checked Selector API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/#entry-longdesc)

> The `:checked` selector works for checkboxes and radio buttons.
>   For select elements, use the `:selected` selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $("input").val($(this).find("option:checked").text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/QMXEn/

Comment: Those are awfully broad selectors. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - The rest is on him to figure it out. ;)